# React Native + Firebase Auth - displayName

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a registry screen inside an application made with React Native. I am using Firebase authentication to create a new user.

On the login screen, I'm using .signInWithEmailAndPassword (to access an account), and on the registration screen I'm using .createUserWithEmailAndPassword (to create a user), and reading articles about Firebase authentication, I know I can use displayName to receive the name user, and photoUrl to receive a photo of the user.

What I would like to do is create a new user using the username, email and password. Even reading articles on the subject, I don't know a way to do this.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
signup() {
   this.setState({
     // When waiting for the firebase server show the loading indicator.
     loading: true
   });
   // Make a call to firebase to create a new user.
  this.props.firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((userData) => {
   // then and catch are methods that we call on the Promise returned from
   // createUserWithEmailAndPassword
   Alert.alert('Success', 'Congrats!', [{text: 'OK!', onPress: this.dismiss}]);
   this.setState({
     // Clear out the fields when the user logs in and hide the progress indicator.
     email: '',
     password: '',
     loading: false
   });
   AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
   this.props.navigator.push({
     component: Account
   });
 }).catch((error) => {
     // Leave the fields filled when an error occurs and hide the progress indicator.
     this.setState({
       loading: false
     });
     Alert.alert('Ops', 'Error: ' + error.message, [{text: 'OK!', onPress: this.dismiss}]);
  });
}
```

Basically I want to create a new user with the user name, email and password using the Firebase Authentication.

Can any of you guys give me an example of how I can create a user with username, email, and password?

If you want to see what I'm trying to do, I created a project to improve my knowledge in React Native? https://github.com/JoaoVRodrigues01/React-Native-Codec-App

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support sign in with username/password:

On sign up you can ask for username, email and password.
You create the account with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and then save a mapping of username to email in the Firebase Database while ensuring uniqueness of username.

The next time a user signs in with username and password, you can get the email from the username and then `signInWithEmailAndPassword` using that email and password provided.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! In the login screen, the user will enter the account using the email and password, and in the registration screen, the user will create an account using the name, email and password. I want to ask the user name in the registry to return the user information on a screen, there will be displayed user account information such as user name and email.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your use case.

Comment: Basically I want to create a user with the user name, email and password using the Firebase Authentication. But no problem. Thank you anyway!